# how to keep a GUI on-screen without moving or resizing it according to camera movement

Tags: c++, user-interface, camera, blur, sfml

Hey i'm trying to make a GUI lib with SFML, and everything's done except one problem: Making the Interface stay still even when the camera moves or zooms in.

This would be easy to fix if zooming wasn't possible, but **zooming out means scaling the contents of the Interface up, which causes it's text/images to become blurry**.

*Does anyone have a way to get around this issue?* (***preferably only using SFML***, but if i must i can add OpenGL stuff....)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stop using the same camera and perspective matrices for your GUI as you do for your scene.

In the case of SFML apply a different view, then restore the old one.